# why my emails with wp_mail function is known as spam

Tags: php, wordpress

i use wp_mail function in wordpress to send mail but my email is know as spam in yahoo,..

i use same following code

```
$headers = 'From: myname <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n\\"; 

 wp_mail('myemailonyahoo@yahoo.com', 'The subject', 'The message',$headers);
```

please give a Suggestion ?

thanks

Comment: It might well be what "the message" contains.

Comment: When you change your From-header (in support@google.com for example), does it still get marked as spam? That could mean your domain-name is marked as spam instead of the message itself.

Comment: @ceejayoz i tested other contain message but yahopo marks it spam

Comment: Refer following article on coding horror - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html - that might help

Comment: @Tim van Elsloo, when i use  From-header myemail@gmail.com , it still marks as spam

Answer (score 2):

This is probably nothing to do with wordpress and everything to do with spam protection methods ... are you allowed to send email for that domain? Trying to send  from x@gmail.com will definitely get you marked as spam - google SPF records for why, then make sure you have one. Make sure your email comes from a reputable domain that's installed properly on your server.